# What type of circuit breaker do I need for a replacement?

Tags: circuit-breaker, circuit

I need some assistance repairing my dad's trailer/mobile home electrical panel. He told me a part (circuit breaker, image attached to this post) to be replaced and he’s not sure which brand/kind/model to replace it with.

It’s an older trailer so I’m sure they don’t make the same circuit breakers so I need help finding out which one is compatible and affordable, I’m only trying to replace the black box that’s posted to this post.

Image 1:  (50)  (20)

Image 2: CURRENT INTERRUPTING RATING MAX. RMS SYM, AMPERES  10.000 A7 20/240 VOLTS AC

Image 3: USE ONLY IN LISTED ENCLOSURE 40C CTL PATENTS:  3.088.006 3.200.217 2.797.278  3.110.786 3.254.176 A MADE IN U.S.A.

Can anybody please give me a hand with this, Thank You!

[image]

Comment: That looks like a 50A/20A tandem breaker. Which sounds very unusual to me. Typically tandems are 15/15, 15/20 or 20/20. Most circuits larger than 20A are double-pole - i.e., a 50/20/20/50 or 20/50/50/20 quad makes sense but not a 50/20 pair. What is powered by this breaker?

Comment: Get a picture of the labeling on the inside of the panel door - particularly the brand & model information. Based on the lovely, chicklets colors of the breaker handles, I have a feeling that this is one of those "Replace this panel. Yesterday!" panels, but _I_ couldn't tell you that for certain.

Comment: I think this is a Bryant breaker, brand acquisition could be labeled as Westinghouse, Eaton, or Cutler Hammer. If brand can be confirmed then  https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.BD2050.html is likely your replacement.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease it looks like a Murray EP to me, I'd still go with your cross though I would be wary of it not actually being code compliant. It should work though.

Comment: If you can't locate a breaker, another option is a retrofit interior. These allow you to rewire the whole panel without replacement, so you can use modern breakers. If you're just doing a panel interior you don't have to bring everything else up to code.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease The U.S. patent numbers were originally assigned to Westinghouse (if that helps).

Comment: We need to see a picture of the whole panel and the other breakers.  I have a big problem with the "50" on that breaker because the color says 15/20A (that'd be an Eaton BR1520) but the handle says 50/20 (not a thing); to see what's *really* happening we need context. Need a pic of the whole panel.  Don't make "scrapbooks". Do use good light. Max resolution please. To mash down the megabytes for upload, go "Save As"... JPEG... quality (0-12) choose 2 or 3.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica 50/20 apparently *is* a thing - see link in NoSparksPlease comment. But I find it highly suspect.

Comment: Google shows me lots of apparently-modern examples of 50-20 _quads_, with the two 50s in the middle and handle-tied.

Comment: @manassehkatz the problem is there's no conceivable use for a 50A/120V breaker, except handle-tied to serve a really big A/C.   That BD2050 might be in the catalog, but lots of Eaton things are in the catalog *and not on any shelf anywhere*.