# I need help replacing a circuit breaker in my dads trailer/mobile home

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I need some assistance repairing my dad's trailer/mobile home electrical panel. He told me a part (circuit breaker, image attached to this post) to be replaced and he’s not sure which brand/kind/model to replace it with.  It’s an older trailer so I’m sure they don’t make the same circuit breakers so I need help finding out which one is compatible and affordable, I’m only trying to replace the black box that’s posted to this post.

Image 1:  (50)  (20)

Image 2: CURRENT INTERRUPTING RATING MAX. RMS SYM, AMPERES  10.000 A7 20/240 VOLTS AC

Image 3: USE ONLY IN LISTED ENCLOSURE 40C CTL PATENTS:  3.088.006 3.200.217 2.797.278  3.110.786 3.254.176 A MADE IN U.S.A.

[image]

Can anybody please give me a hand with this, Thank You!

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/271831/what-type-of-circuit-breaker-do-i-need-for-a-replacement It also looks like you have two different user accounts.

Comment: As the comments on your first question asked, we need to know the panel make.  Breakers need to fit right in a panel.  Ones that almost fit right can be dangerous.  The experts on here will tell you the right type of breaker you need for that panel as soon as you give them the information.

Comment: The way StackExchange works, nearly all communication is via the public pages, not through email. Ask a question, people answer or ask for more details via comments, you respond to comments or add more details to the original question, etc. until (hopefully) you get a useful answer.

Comment: Look this is my first time using this. Iam not trying to be deceitful. When I made the first post I was using the site like a GUEST, then I decided to add my email so I made another post, that’s when I created my first and only account. I’m hoping somebody emails me, this site is confusing and I keep loosing the post. I’m not tech savvy as most of you are so, so as soon as I get my answer, I’ll be outta your way.

Comment: If you want to merge your guest and registered accounts, use the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page then "Account issue" and select the "I need to merge user profiles" option, then fill out the form. As noted earlier, private email for answers is not how this site works, so I've edited that out of your post. Good luck!

Comment: Freddy, don't feel bad. It is very confusing for new users, and there are a number of things that I think could be improved about how the system works, but beyond our (DIY members) control.

Comment: Yeah, this site is confusing because it's not a forum. It's a Q&A site and works a little differently.  The rules keep quality high, which is why you picked this place and not answers.yahoo.com. **You are not a nuisance AT ALL**.  You're just struggling with the format; don't worry, that's temporary.   That said, it's important to read comments and answer those followup questions.  Every question is for the purpose of solving your problem, which is bigger than you realize. If you are seen snubbing people's followup questions, no one will help you.

Comment: My followup question was I need to see a photo of the panel this is coming out of, so we can figure what's up with that *very strange* 50A breaker. Any panel labeling would be valuable as well as telling us what it switches. I know you want this to be a unit swap, *but it's not* because that product went obsolete *for reasons*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica in reply to your comment on the other copy of this question, I actually found two places that claim stock of that very weird breaker.

Comment: @KMJ But *what's the application*?  This breaker is an odd duck because there's almost no safe/legal use for it.  99% chance they're overfusing something or really need a quadplex with handle ties or common trip.  We ought to have that conversation with OP for their own safety.  If OP doesn't care, the model is Eaton BR2050. (BD2050 probably won't work as it's a CTL breaker).